# Time Series Heat Map

Tags: r

I wish to create a single heatmap using ggplot including following factors:
year-month, mkt_name, mp_price

str(df)

```
   'data.frame':    2655 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ year      : int  2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 2012 ...
 $ yearmonthf: Factor w/ 48 levels "Jan 2012","Feb 2012",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ month     : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ mkt_name  : Factor w/ 63 levels "Base","Birambo",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ mp_price  : num  145 136 160 163 181 ...
```

```
df <- read.csv('/Users/shashankshekhar/Desktop/R Food Price/Foodprice/datasets/Correlation/Heatmap/Potatoesheat.csv')
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)  # format date
df <- df[df$year >= 2012, ]  # filter reqd years

# Create Month Week
df$yearmonth <- as.yearmon(df$date)
df$yearmonthf <- factor(df$yearmonth)
df <- df[, c("year", "yearmonthf", "month", "mkt_name", "mp_price")]
```

head(df)

```
   year yearmonthf month mkt_name mp_price
15 2012   Jan 2012     1  Birambo   145.00
16 2012   Feb 2012     2  Birambo   136.25
17 2012   Mar 2012     3  Birambo   160.00
18 2012   Apr 2012     4  Birambo   162.75
19 2012   May 2012     5  Birambo   181.00
20 2012   Jun 2012     6  Birambo   170.00
```

Heatmap ggplot

```
ggplot(df, aes(mkt_name, year, fill = mp_price)) + 
  geom_tile(colour = "white") + 
  facet_grid(year~mkt_name) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="green") +
  labs(x="Week of Month",
       y="",
       title = "Time-Series Calendar Heatmap", 
       subtitle="Potato Price", 
       fill="Price")
```

Comment: Also take a look at the ComplexHeat package. It is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mis-attributed your variables. Instead try:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = yearmonth, y = mkt_name, fill = mp_price))+
  geom_tile()+
  scale_x_date(date_labels = "%b %Y")+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="green") +
  labs(x="Week of Month",
       y="",
       title = "Time-Series Calendar Heatmap", 
       subtitle="Potato Price", 
       fill="Price")
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

---

**reproducible  example**

```r
df <- data.frame(mkt_name = rep("Birambo",6),
                 year = 2012,
                 yearmonth = seq(as.Date("2012-01-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d"), as.Date("2012-06-01", format = "%Y-%m-%d"), by = "month"),
                 month = 1:6,
                 mp_price = c(145,136.25,160,162.75,181,170))
```

Comment: Thanks for helping but when I am trying to run the code you did I am getting this error
```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'yearmonth' not found
```
Is there should be yearmonthf instead, can you please help me with that?

Comment: Yes, because I have to made the example by myself, so colnames are not exactly the same as yours. Just changes `yearmonth` to `yearmonthf` in `ggplot2` code. (BTW, it's good practice to provide a reproducible example when asking a question on SO:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).